# c# excel dll - can't add a reference to the specified file - regasm

Tags: c#, dll, windows-vista, excel-2007, regasm

When deploying and registering a `.Net` `Excel.dll` on another computer, I get an error `Can't add a reference to the specified file` when attempting to add reference to `DLL` in `VBA` editor.

I have created the `Excel.dll` in `C#` in `Visual Studio` that runs fine on my machine with `Windows 7` and `Office 2010`. No problem adding reference to the dll in `Excel VBA` editor on my computer. My problem is deploying on another machine which is running `Vista` and `Excel 2007`. I copied dll to this computer and used `regasm` to register the dll.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Here is code and regasm:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe excelDll.dll

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestDll
{
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
public class Test
{
    public string HelloWorld
    {
        get
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }

    public void sayGoodbye1()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Say Goodbye");

    }

    public string sayGoodbye2()
    {
        return "Say Goodbye";
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to register the type library for excel to see your dll in References.

i.e. `regasm.exe excelDll.dll /tlb:excelDll.tlb`

Mark.

Answer (score -1):

I recently encountered and managed to solve exactly this problem - though I can't claim to understand exactly *why* my solution worked.

Both my systems are running Windows 7 x64.  One has Excel 2010, the other Excel 2007.

All the C# assemblies are set to "Platform Target: Any CPU".  The primary assembly is set to "Register for COM Interop".  The whole thing is installed using an MSI created by a Visual Studio Installer project.

I found that if I set the Visual Studio Installer project "Target Platform" to "x64", then it works in Excel 2010, but not in Excel 2007.  Conversely, if I set the Visual Studio Installer project "Target Platform" to "x86", it works in Excel 2007 but not in Excel 2010.

Sadly, I'm not in a position to test both Excel versions on the same machine at the same time - but at least this might get it working for you!

Comment: Just to add to my post above - I was getting both the reported "cannot add a reference" error, and (if I used CreateObject without adding a reference) a "License not available" error.